# 301 htaccess переадресация на url без слэша

Tags: javascript, php, веб-программирование, .htaccess, redirect

Есть страницы, вида

```
http://www.example.ru/page.php
```

Я убираю у нее расширение,чтобы выглядело лаконичнее

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Теперь url выглядит так

```
http://www.example.ru/page
```

Проблема в том, что есть источники,где ссылка хранится в таком виде
`http://www.example.ru/page/`

Хочу сделать переадресацию с `http://www.example.ru/page/` --> `http://www.example.ru/page`

Пробовал так

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\&
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![^\/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

и так

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..{1,10}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.ru/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Не помогло

Comment: Ответ на Ваш вопрос - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url

Comment: Спасибо,помогло